# Get Text from Range - VBA (Excel)

Tags: list, excel, validation, user-defined-functions, vba

I want to make a data validation list from text only in a Range of cells.

I searched for formula but I found nothing so I decided to make my own function but its not working.

I tried those codes:

Code 1:

```
Function ListFromRange(rng As Range) As Range

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim entry As Range

    For Each cl In rng
        If Not IsNumeric(cl.Value) Or cl.Value = "" Then
            If entry Is Nothing Then
                Set entry = cl
            Else
                Set entry = Union(entry, cl)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set ListFromRange = entry
End Function
```

Code 2:

```
Function ListFromRange2(rng As Range) As Variant

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim entry() As String
    ReDim entry(rng.Count)

    For Each cl In rng
        If Not IsNumeric(cl.Value) Or cl.Value = "" Then
            entry(i) = cl.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    ListFromRange2 = entry
End Function
```

The second code is working but when I use with a defined name and use that defined name for data validation list its tells me that there is an error in the validation list source but when I use this function with index its returning the desired result.

Also some images to explain more:

[image: Source Range]

I want to make a list from cells that contains a text and apply it here:

[image: Target List]

But without the number values.

Comment: I think you want you `If` statement to actually be `If Not IsNumeric(cl.Value) And Not cl.Value = "" Then`. The `Not` applies to each statement individually if you don't bracket your logic. Also return a `Range` not a `Variant` on the first line. Finally, *what are you trying to **do***?? You've not actually said. Currently your function returns a range of cells which contain non-numeric values... why is that wrong / what else do you want it to do?

Comment: The validation list is not working for my UDF, what you see in the image is a validation for the entire row so number values were included.

Comment: Okay, have you updated your logic as I suggested above? Then are you sure you're clearing and updating the values in the drop down? There is no way that `IsNumeric("12,300")` is returning false so your logic is okay, it must be other code you aren't showing which is failing.

Comment: Problem was not in logic as I tried this function with the formula `INDEX` and it is returning the desired values, but those values I can't put them in a data validation list, I also tried Defined Names with my custom function and is not working for data validation list. (I will edit my main question with better illustration)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the resultant range is multiple columns and cannot be used as the source for a Data Validation List. If you cannot change the design of the table of options so that it is just one column, you need to find another way to set up the Validation List.

Here is a solution using VBA. I put this in a sub that can be run on demand as a macro, but you might drop it into a worksheet event that triggers when data on the sheet changes or some other event.

This will only create the validation list as far down as there is data in Column A. You'll probably want to carry it down further than this, or as mentioned, put this into a worksheet event so that it updates the Validation list as new rows are added.

I set up my sheets as follows, but you can also download my example [here](http://hubbyclub.com/misc/VBA_RangeValidationList.xlsm).

[image: Basic Price]

[image: Example]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Validation_List()
    Dim rngList As Range, cl As Range
    Dim rngValidationList As Range
    Dim strList As String

    Set rngList = Worksheets("BasicPrice").Range("A2:F3")
    strList = ""
    For Each cl In rngList
        If Not IsNumeric(cl.Value) And Not cl.Value = "" Then strList = strList & "," & cl.Value  'Add to our Validation List
    Next cl
    strList = Mid(strList, 2)   'Chop off leading comma

    'Apply Data Validation to this Range (starting at cell C2 and ending at the last row with data in column A)
    Set rngValidationList = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With rngValidationList.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=strList                  'Pass in Validation List created above
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is interesting but I can't put the `Basic Price-Brand` range in another sheet in fact this range must be adjacent to the table that I am trying to make the data validation list to and their number of rows are identical, also, each row in the table has a data validation list for brands in the same row in `Basic Price-Brand` range not the entire range rows, anyways, I got your point in the code and will make a few adjustments to suit it to my needs. Thanks

Comment: Absolutely, you can put the Basic Price Brand range anywhere needed, just redirect the Range to that location in the code. Let me know if you need any help.